# How can a (wizard) lich remove his paralysis from a victim?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions

## Anyone from my group - Don't read! spoilers ahead! :)

---

So, last session one of the PCs got kidnapped by Big-Bad-Evil-Guy lich.
Said PC failed the save against the lich's paralyzing touch attack which reads:

> **Special Attacks**: [...] paralysis (permanent, DC 25)

Now, this specific BBEG is an *atrophied lich* (his level went down to wizard 9), and is ancient (10,000+ years of existence). He has a vast arcane and alchemical lab in his tomb, which he seldom leaves, but only non-casting allies and minions.

He has *charmed* the PC, and now wishes to allow her more mobility (so she can draw maps for him etc.).

**Is there any RAW means the lich can use to undo his own the paralysis** without resorting to UMD and divine scrolls/wands?

This doesn't have to be a permanent solution. Anything which doesn't require modifying his character's build is preferred.

Thanks!

---

Details about *atrophied lich*:

> **Atrophied Lich** (Ex) A lich that remains immobile and insensible for extended periods of time can grow atrophied. The exact effects of atrophy vary from lich to lich. Example, his effective wizard level could decline from 20th to 9th. Note that these are not negative levels–the atrophied lich must earn back the lost XP normally. [...]

Comment: By the way, where does "atrophied lich" come from? Is it 3PP?

Comment: Its a special ability given to a big bad boss at the rise of runelords adventure path. I had to search my pdfs to find it. So i don't think it has been published anywhere else.

Comment: @MGlacier, ShadowKras - this one actually comes from Kingmaker ch.3 (perhaps Rise of the Runelords is the first appearance, IDK)

Comment: You are correct, he is from kingmaker, i dont know why i was thinking about runelords when i did find him on the kingmaker pdfs.

Answer (score 10):

The [Lich template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lich/) reads:

> Paralyzing Touch (Su)
>
> Any living creature a lich hits with its touch attack must succeed on a Fortitude save or be permanently paralyzed. **Remove paralysis or any spell that can remove a curse can free the victim** (see the bestow curse spell description, with a DC equal to the lich’s save DC). The effect cannot be dispelled. Anyone paralyzed by a lich seems dead, though a DC 20 Perception check or a DC 15 Heal check reveals that the victim is still alive.

So, [Break Enchantment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/break-enchantment/) and [Remove Curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-curse/) are both viable options for a wizard 9 character.